# Google map setClustering(ClusteringSettings) method not resolving

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to use [Google Maps Extension](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions) in my app. But when i try to use setClustering method to my Google Map object its showing not resolving error, that means google map class does not have this method.

```
mMap.setClustering(new ClusteringSettings().enabled(false).addMarkersDynamically(true));
```

However, according to library documentation i have to use like this. Also the available Stackoverflow answers also did like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120798/load-only-markers-surrounding-my-location-google-map-v2-android) way.

this is my dependency

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:12.0.1'
compile 'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GoogleMap` should be `com.androidmapsextensions.GoogleMap` not `com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap` check your import.

```
com.androidmapsextensions.GoogleMap map;



 map.setClustering(new ClusteringSettings().enabled(false).addMarkersDynamically(true));
```